# How to use usemap with a FadeSlideShow?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I'm trying to set the usemap attribute to one of these images which are added to the imagearray. The code below is a FadeSlide in javascript, but I'd like to instantiate some map attributes over one of those images. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
    wrapperid: "fadeshow1",
    dimensions: [250, 180],
    imagearray: [
        ["http://i26.tinypic.com/11l7ls0.jpg", "", "", "Nothing beats relaxing next to the pool when the weather is hot."],
        ["http://i29.tinypic.com/xp3hns.jpg", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave", "_new", "Some day I'd like to explore these caves!"]
    ],
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:2500, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
    persist: false, 
    fadeduration: 500,
    descreveal: "ondemand",
    togglerid: ""
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add it with JS code like

```
$('#fadeshow1').find('img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('usemap', '#imgmap');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a different plugin.

The problem is that `FadeSlide` generates markup for you instead of enhancing existing markup in your document. That makes your choices limited if you want to use some custom markup for the images (e.g. `usemap` attribute). Also it violates [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) principle.

If you use some plugin like [JQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) you can incorporate sitemap easily:

```
<div id="slider">
  <img src="http://img1.jpg" width="200" height="200" usemap="#mymap1" />
  <img src="http://img2.jpg" width="200" height="200" usemap="#mymap2" />
</div>
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
$('#slider').cycle();
```

That plugin is also very robust in terms of different options.

Comment: Had the same problem with the [Galleria](http://galleria.io/) plugin, cycle, and especially its improved version [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) are really awsome.